# How may seconds may an API call take until I need to worry?

Tags: django, ajax, api, server

I have to ask a more or less non-typical SO question and hope you don't mind. Right now I am developing my very first web application. I did set up an AJAX function that requests some data from a third party API and populates my html containers with the returned data.

Right now I query one single object and populate 3 html containers with around 15 lines of Javascript code. When i activate the process/function by clicking a button on my frontend, it needs around 6-7 seconds until the html content is updated.

Is this a reasonable time? The user experience honestly will be more than bad considering that I will have to query and manipulate far more data (I build a one-site dashboard related to soccer data).

There might be very controversal answers to that question, but what would be a fair enough time for the process to run using standard infrastructure? 1-2 seconds? (I will deploy the app on heroku or digitalocean and will implement a proper caching environment to handle "regular visitors").

Right now

- I use a virtualenv and django server for the development
- and a demo server from the third party API which might be slowed down for whatever reason (how to check this?)

which might effect the current time needed (there will be many more variables obv.).

Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think (probably a lot people might too) 6-7 secs is a significant delay for rendering a small page. The cause of this issue might not came from django directly. Check for the following:

1. I use a virtualenv and django server for the development

   - you may be running django devserver, production server might make things bit faster (use django-debug-toolbar to find what causing the delay)
   - Do db index in your model.
2. a demo server from the third party API which might be slowed down for whatever reason

   - use chrome developer tools 'network' tab to watch how long that third party call takes. it might not visible there if you call api in your view.py. in that case, add some timing code there to calculate how long it takes to return.